# Undefined when Filtering an Array in React JS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter

I am trying to filter an array in React for only certain items (in my case I want all items that have `type: "Plant"`). I can get the data from an API successfully but filtering its produces this error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.Array.object')`

Here is what the data looks like if I console log it:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP6Pj.png)

Here is my full code:

```
import React from "react";
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import { listTrackerItems } from '../graphql/queries';

class TrackerPlantsPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    plant:'',
    plants: [],
    active: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listTrackerItems))
    let data = result.data.listTrackerItems.items
    console.log(data)
    let activePlants = data.Array.filter(t=>t.type === 'Plant');
    this.setState({active: activePlants, plants: data });
  }

  render() {
    const { plants, active } = this.state
    console.log(plants)

    return (
      <>
      <div class="container">

        {/* Cards */}
              <div id="toggle-harvested" class="">
              <div class="uk-child-width-1-3 uk-grid-small uk-grid-match uk-grid">
                {plants.map(item => (
                            <div key={item.id} class="uk-margin-top uk-margin-bottom">
                                <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body">
                                    <div class="uk-card-badge uk-label">Harvested on {item.harvestDate}</div>
                                        <div class="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" uk-grid>
                                            <div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-margin-remove-bottom">{item.name}</h3>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul class="uk-list uk-list-striped">
                                            <li>Planted: {item.todaysDate}</li>
                                            <li>Assigned: {item.assignedUser}</li>
                                            <li>{item.description}</li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default TrackerPlantsPage;
```

Regards

Comment: It's just data.filter, not data.Array.filter

Comment: we really need to see what you get as a return value from GraphQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do `data.filter(t => t.type === 'Plant')` instead.

Comment: ah, the rookie mistakes. Thanks for the help!